# How to locate button through child div in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, button, parent

I want to click a button that does not have an ID nor a unique class name and can only be found through child divs. The button says Export to GPS Device, however, this text is not in the button element but in some div below.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXeCa.png)

What I tried:

- locate element by link text / locate element through search for text
- get (for now) one parent of the div with text that says Export to GPS Device

This approach failed because I cannot even correctly locate the child element.

```
# alternative 1
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Export To GPS Device")))

# alternative 2
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Export To GPS Device')]")))

##
one_parent = element.parent
```

Does this approach make sense? If so, how can I locate the child element and identify the correct parent which should be the export button?

Answer (score 1):

This XPath should work:

```
//button[.//div[contains(text(),'Export To GPS Device')]]
```